# How to filter a struct containing a string and an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, data-manipulation

Basically this is a struct object holding a country and its ports

```
struct countryAndPorts {
   var country: String?
   var ports: [String]?
}
```

These are the arrays holding each country mapped to its ports. The filtered array should hold filtered results either by country or ports.

```
var countryAndPortsArray = [countryAndPorts]()
var filteredArray = [countryAndPorts]()
```

Currently the function below successfully produces a filtered result using countries as search key

```
func filteredContent(searchKey: String) {
    filteredArray = countryAndPortsArray.flatMap{ $0 }.filter{$0.country?.lowercased().range(of: searchKey) != nil }
}
```

Now my problem is I wish to get a filtered result either by using a port or country as search key. I have tried my possible best but can't seem to get desirable results using ports as the search key. Improvements on my current method would be much appreciated. Answers in Objective-C are welcomed as well.

```
//Just incase it's of any use, these are my UITableView delegates 
extension SearchDealsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = filteredArray[section].ports?.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if let port = filteredArray[indexPath.section].ports?[indexPath.row] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = port
    }
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return filteredArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    portsFromTextField.text = filteredArray[indexPath.section].ports?[indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header")
    let tapSectionHeaderGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(getCountryText(sender:)))
    tapSectionHeaderGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapSectionHeaderGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    header?.addGestureRecognizer(tapSectionHeaderGesture)

    if header != nil {
        header?.textLabel?.textColor = THEME_COLOUR
        header?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        header?.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[section].country
    }

    return header
}

func getCountryText(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let country = sender.view as? UITableViewCell {
        portsFromTextField.text = country.textLabel?.text
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}
```

**-------------------------------- UDPATE -------------------------------**

At the moment typing "vlone" as a search string returns both "vlone" and "vlore". Vlone and Vlore are both  ports in Albania

[Result yielded using vlone as search string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYfdN.png)

However the desired output should only include "vlone" and leave out every other port in Albania because the user was specific with their query.

2nd scenario would be using "barcelona" as search key. It returns a result containing every port in Spain however the desired output should only contain Barcelona.

[Results using barcelona as search key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T69S9.png)

Comment: Why define a struct for the mapping? Just use `var countriesAndPorts = [String : [String]]()`, and get a country's ports by calling `let ports = countriesAndPorts["Spain"]`.

Comment: @NRitH A structure is better than a dictionary. There might be other properties, there might be logic that can be added, etc.

Comment: @NRitH I saw it somewhere online but did not give it much thought. Normally i use structs to build slightly complex data structures rather than classes.

Comment: @rmaddy In the OP's case, it's simply a mapping of ports to their countries. No need to over-engineer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter the array to find any entry that has a matching country or port, then you can do:

```
func filteredContent(searchKey: String) {
    filteredArray = countryAndPortsArray.filter {
        $0.country?.lowercased().range(of: searchKey) != nil ||
        !($0.ports?.filter {
            $0.lowercased().range(of: searchKey) != nil
        }.isEmpty ?? true)
    }
}
```

Let's break this down. At the top level is the call to `filter` on the `countryAndPortsArray` array. The filter consists of two parts. 1) checking to see if the country contains the search text, and 2) checking to see if any of the ports contain the search text.

The first check is done with:

```
$0.country?.lowercased().range(of: searchKey) != nil
```

which is the part you already had.

The second check is done with:

```
!($0.ports?.filter {
    $0.lowercased().range(of: searchKey) != nil
}.isEmpty ?? true)
```

Since `ports` is an array, a filter is being used to see if any of the ports contains the search text. The `isEmpty` is checking if the resulting filter list of matching ports is empty. Since `ports` is optional, the use of `?? true` means to act as if the list of matching ports is empty. The `!` negates the results. So if the matching list is empty (or `ports` is `nil`), the `true` is negated to `false` indicating that there are no matching ports.

The two checks are combined using the standard logical "or" operator `||` meaning only one of the two checks needs to be true for the top level filter to match that record.

Comment: @maddy Ahh life saver, works perfectly. Don't mean to be a pain but if you could spare a few minutes to give me a break down of your solution, that would be great . Still getting a hang of these higher order functions in general. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation. Is that clearer?

Comment: Thanks it's much clearer. One more thing, right now if I search "London" it brings up every port in England and South Africa (apparently theres a port called "East London" in SA). Is it possible to only bring up ports matching "London"?

Comment: You can change the code to do whatever you want. Right now you are using `range(of:)`. If you want an exact match then simply compare the two strings.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I did not make my question clear enough, currently the filtered array contains all ports within the same country as the search port however i would want the array to hold only the search port if there's an exact match. I think what i need to do some how reduce the array further before it's returned to `filteredArray` but the logic fails me :(

Comment: No, your requirement is not clear. I strongly suggest you update your question to clearly show several examples of input and output that you expect for a given search string.

Comment: Updated my question, hope the linked images will make things clearer. Thanks